# SQLAlchemy and foreign keys in reflected tables

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy

I'm a little bit stuck with a problem related to SQLAlchemy and reflected tables, which are connected with a foreign key.

I have two tables:

```sql
result_table:
=============
| id | team_home | team_visitor | result |
| -- | --------- | ------------ | ------ |
|  1 |         1 |            2 |    3:2 |
|  2 |         1 |            3 |    2:0 |

team_table:
===========
| id | team_name |
| -- | --------- |
|  1 | Hawks     |
|  2 | Sparrows  |
|  3 | Eagles    |
```

Now, those tables already exist in the database. I created them using PGAdmin and filled them with sample data. `team_home`and `team_visitor` are both foreign keys pointing to `team_table.id`.

With SQLAlchemy I use declaration to reflect them:

```py
from sqlalchemy import MetaData, Table, create_engine
from sqlalchemy.engine.url import URL
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base

database = {
            ...
           }

engine = create_engine(URL(**database))

Base = declarative_base()
meta = MetaData()

class Results(Base):
    __table__ = Table('result_table', meta, autoload=True, autoload_with=engine)

class Teams(Base):
    __table__ = Table('team_table', meta, autoload=True, autoload_with=engine)
```

Querying each table isn't a problem, but I'm not able to join them. A statement like `session.query(Results, Teams).join(Teams).all()` will result in a `AmbiguousForeignKeysError`.

The result should be:

```
| id | team_home | team_visitor | result |
| -- | --------- | ------------ | ------ |
|  1 | Hawks     | Sparrows     |    3:2 |
|  2 | Hawks     | Eagles       |    2:0 |
```

Viewing the metadata I cleary see that the foreign key is loaded. Now I'm stuck. I'm sure that I miss a column within my class declaring the relationship (like `relationship("Address", foreign_keys=[billing_address_id])`) but since the definition of that class is reflected, the names of the foreign keys are not avaible at calling time (or instancing time).

Anyway, any hints from outside on how to get foreign keys working within reflected tables? Or should it be better to override the table definition in its class?

Many thanks for your patience.

Regards, Thomas

**UPDATE**

It's a lot easier using just the core functionality of SQLAlchemy:

```
# database connection expected for this example

from sqlalchemy import MetaData
from sqlalchemy.sql import select, alias
import pandas as pd

metadata = MetaData()
metadata.reflect(bind=engine)

res_table = metadata.tables['result_table']
tt_home = metadata.tables['team_table'].alias('team_table_home')
tt_vis = metadata.tables['team_table'].alias('team_table_visitor')

s = select([
    res_table.c.id, 
    tt_home.c.team_name, 
    tt_vis.c.team_name,
    res_table.c.result
    ]).select_from(
        res_table.join(
            tt_home, res_table.c.team_home == tt_home.c.id
        ).join(
            tt_vis, res_table.c.team_visitor == tt_vis.c.id)
    ).order_by(res_table.c.id)

result_df = pd.read_sql_query(s, engine).set_index('id')
```

Hope this might help somebody else as well when struggeling joining two tables connected with two foreign keys.

Cheers, Thomas

Answer (score 1):

you can try this -

```
session.query(Results, Teams).join(Teams, Teams.id==Results.team_home).all()
```

Answer (score 0):

not sure if this is the source of your problem, since you say that your metadata loads correctly, but I load the metadata with a bind=engine argument right away

```
metadata = db.MetaData(bind=engine)
```

db is sqlalchemy object.

I also load tables without a class and just make a reference to it like this:

```
results_table = db.Table('result_table', metadata, autoload=True)
```

without the autoload_with=engine argument.

Comment: Hi, I reconsidered my idea and I guess it's better to use SQLAlchemy's core functionality than ORM. Makes life a lot easier. I'll post the solution for this whenever I have it. Cheers and thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I was looking for a way to  check that my Foreign keys columns has been created succesfully (they are reflected in the MEtaData)
So What I did is:

```
from sqlalchemy import *
engine = sqlalchemy.create_engine('sqlite:///yourdb.db')#, echo=True)

metadata = MetaData()
metadata.reflect(engine)
tbl = Table('mytable', metadata)
for column in tbl.c:
    print (column.name)
    print(column.foreign_keys)
```